# ASP.NET Core Web API try catch exception question

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my API, I have over 25 API controllers, in every controller, using the following code to catch exception, I think it is too many code here,  any good suggestion for the structure, thanks.

```
            try
            {
               *code here*
            }            
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
            }
            catch (BadRequestException ex)
            {
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
            }
            catch (TimeoutRejectedException ex)
            {
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
            }
            catch (ValidationException ex)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

Any simple way to do that.

Comment: Why are you catching the exceptions?  Are you planning to handle them (do something useful in the exception handler)?  If not, just let them bubble up.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+core+centralized+exception+handling

Comment: Thank you Kirk, I will save the exception to the log file, too many catch.

Comment: @Stephen if you are not doing anything to the exceptions except logging them, then `Exception ex` would be enough. You don't need to sepecify a specific exception unless you need to handle it (say for instance, an SqlException throws, and you needto go through some steps to handle SqlException, and then re-try to execute the command again ..etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF**

you plan to handle each exception **separately** - your approach is the way to go. I suggest to use this "ugly" code simply because it is more readable. If **all your exceptions** have common handling (for example logging) - you can use only `catch (Exception e)` and call your logging methods. This will work for all types of exceptions.

**OR**

If you decide that **some of your exceptions** might have common handling - you can go with:

```
try 
{
    // do
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e is BadRequestException || 
        e is HttpRequestException ||
        e is TimeoutRejectedException ) 
    {
        // Log exception
    }
}
```

**OR**

A good approach is to use a delegate for exception handling. Since you're going to log exceptions, the delegate will handle this.

```
Action<Exception> HandleError = (e) => {
    // Log exception
};

catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e) { HandleError(e); }
catch (BadRequestException e) { HandleError(e); }
catch (HttpRequestException e) { HandleError(e); }
```

**OR**

You can combine the first and the second approach

```
if (e is BadRequestException || 
    e is HttpRequestException ||
    e is TimeoutRejectedException ) 
{
    HandleError(e);
}
```